# USB w/Ubuntu show startup messages?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, startup

Typically in an installed version of Ubuntu NOT on a USB but installed on a computer, it's easy to show startup messages.  Is there any equivalent when using an install of Ubuntu 20.04 on a startup USB disk, i.e., the installation media of Ubutnu?

Comment: You didn't specify which ISO you're trying to boot... (desktop, server etc) Yes you can; for starters on many boxes you get to see `grub` appear (*allowing change very early*) or you can use ESC...  but that may differ if you're using a different ISO to what I randomly picked up (a random *daily* ISO)

Comment: If you get grub menu, can you not use e for edit and remove quiet splash on the Linux line?